# getting error 200 when i am calling ibm worklight adapter with mobile web application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

we are getting error like

> klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "undefined", errorCode: "API_INVOCATION_FAILURE", errorMsg: "Unsupported environment"…}

when we are calling adapter with mobile web application worklight

my code:

```
    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/testt/getFeed", WLResourceRequest.GET);
    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", []);
    resourceRequest.send().then(
        $scope.branchShowSuccess,
        $scope.branchShowFailure
    );
}

$scope.branchShowSuccess = function(result) {
    alert("success adapter1 "+JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(result);
}

$scope.branchShowFailure = function(data) {
    alert("failure adapter1 "+JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

i am new to this ibm worklight please any help me correct my code

Answer (score 0):

WLResourceRequest is not supported in Mobile Web environment. You need to use WL.Client.invokeProcedure instead.

Comment: How can we invoke JavaAdapter using WL.Client.invokeProcedure from mobile web ?

Comment: Calling a Java adapter from a JavaScript adapter is not possible.